# Getting reference to a parameter of the outer function having a conflicting name

Tags: scala, scope

Please consider this code:

```
trait A {
  def a : Int
}

def f ( a : Int ) = {
  def a0 = a
  new A {
    def a = a0
  }
}
```

The problem is quite evident: `def a0 = a` is a typical annoying boilerplate code and the situation only worsens when more parameters get introduced.

I am wondering if it's possible to somehow get a direct reference to the `a` variable of the outer scope inside the declaration of the instance of the trait and thus to get rid of the intermediate `a0`.

*Please keep in mind that changing name of input parameter of the function is not allowed as is changing the trait.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is *direct* way to do that, because it would require some special (hypothetical) identifier `thisMethod`. However, depending on your context, the following two ways to avoid the name shadowing might be possible:

(1) Replace anonymous class `A` with implementing class:

```
case class AImpl(a: Int) extends A

def f(a : Int): A = AImpl(a)
```

(2) Define `f` in an abstract trait and use a concrete implementation for it:

```
trait F {
  def f(a: Int): A
}

object FImpl extends F {
  def f(a0: Int): A = new A { val a = a0 }
}

def test(factory: F): A = factory.f(a = 33)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest you can get to (without changing your API) is:

```
def f(a: Int) = {
  def ff(a0: Int) = {
    new A {
      def a = a0
    }
  }
  ff(a)
}
```

In Scala, methods are not types. Thus, it is not possible to reference them with the type system or any of there members.

```
scala> class X{def f = 0}
defined class X

scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[X].member(newTermName("f")).isType
res9: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an anonymous solution.

```
package eyeshadow

trait A {
  def a: Int
}

class B {
  def f(a: Int) = {
    val fa: A = new {
      //private val b = a
      private[this] val b = a // crashes, sorry scalac. edit: ok in 2.11
    } with A {
      def a = b
    }
    fa.a
    /*
     * This seems far-fetched, but compare the initial objections in
     * https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3836
     * All I want is to alias a symbol, right?
     * Maybe the override means "do not shadow."
    val fa: A = new A {
      //import fa.{ a => b }
      import this.{ a => b }
      override def b = a
    }
     */
  }
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val b = new B
    println(b f 7)
  }
}
```