# Add a parameter to a case class with a default

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, default-value

I have an existing case class, to which I'd like to add an additional constructor parameter, with a default value, and not disturb existing code that does pattern matching, yet I can't figure out the right approach.

Ie. I have:

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)

def bar(n: Foo) = n match {
  case Foo(1, 2) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Now suppose I need to add an additional parameter, c, to Foo. Ie.

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int, c: Boolean = true)
```

In all existing use cases, the parameter `c` would be true, hence it has that default value. Yet in some new use cases, there is a need to pass false for this.

So it seems sensible to add another parameter, with a default value of `true`. Yet as soon as I do this, the pattern match in `bar` becomes a syntax error. This seems wrong, since I added the default `= true` to ensure that existing constructor calls wouldn't need to be modified.

How can I do this and leave the old pattern matches unchanged?

Update: Note that I also don't want to have to rewrite all the existing instantiations of Foo. @som-snytt pointed out that I could add another parameter as `Foo(a: Int, b: Int)(c: Boolean = true)`, which would be perfect except that it causes existing calls, such as `Foo(1,2)` to fail (they have to be rewritten as `Foo(1,2)()`). I'm looking for a way to add a new parameter only for some use-cases, and avoid rewriting by having a default which works for everywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `case Foo` syntax is not calling a constructor, rather a method called `unapply` on `object Foo`.  case classes autogenerate various boilerplate including the companion object and the unapply.

`unapply` only has one parameter, the object being matched. This keeps you from overloading it since you can't overload on return value in Java/Scala.

So in short you can't do quite what you want.

You can, however, make an extractor with a different name. Here's someone who just added an underscore:
http://x3ro.de/multiple-unapply-methods-for-pattern-matching-in-scala/

perhaps it would be nicer when possible to use a more meaningful name for the extractor variants though.

Here's some more info on how it all works:
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html

You can write out everything a case class does "by hand" and do it differently, such as a different unapply, but it would be pretty annoying assuming you care about equals, hashCode, toString, and all that. If you did that you could maybe avoid having to change existing code but it seems unlikely to be worth it.

Here is an example someone posted:
https://gist.github.com/okapies/2814608

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can live with `case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)(val c: Boolean = true)`.

Update: if you could almost live with that, because you don't want to use the extra param in patterns, then you can make short work of it.

```
package fooplusplus

case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int) {
  def c: Boolean = true
}
object Foo {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int, c: Boolean): Foo =
    new {
      private[this] val x = c // http://stackoverflow.com/a/12239654
    } with Foo(a, b) {
      override def c = x
    }
}

object Test extends App {
  def bar(x: Foo) = x match {
    case Foo(1, 2) if !x.c => 3
    case Foo(1, 2)         => 2 // existing code
    case _                 => 1
  }

  Console println bar(Foo(1, 2))
  Console println bar(Foo(1, 2, c = false))
  Console println bar(Foo(0, 2))
}
```

If you do want pattern matching with the new param, here is one way:

```
case class EnhancedFoo(a: Int, b: Int, c: Boolean)
class Foo(a: Int, b: Int, c: Boolean) extends EnhancedFoo(a, b, c)
object Foo {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int, c: Boolean = true): Foo = new Foo(a, b, c)
  def unapply(x: Foo): Option[(Int, Int)] = Some(x.a, x.b)
}

object Test extends App {
  def bar(x: EnhancedFoo) = x match {
    case EnhancedFoo(1, 2, true) => 3
    case Foo(1, 2)         => 2 // existing code
    case _                 => 1
  }

  Console println bar(Foo(1, 2))
  Console println bar(Foo(1, 2, c = false))
  Console println bar(Foo(0, 2))
}
```

Since we haven't done anything truly whacky yet, how about the following:

```
scala> case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int, c: Boolean*)
defined class Foo

scala> import PartialFunction._
import PartialFunction._

scala> val foo = Foo(1,2)
f: Foo = Foo(1,2,WrappedArray())

scala> val goo = Foo(1,2,true)
g: Foo = Foo(1,2,WrappedArray(true))

scala> cond(foo) { case Foo(1,2) => true }
res0: Boolean = true

scala> cond(goo) { case Foo(1,2,false) => true }
res1: Boolean = false
```

The boolean becomes tri-state, defaulting to old-style empty.

```
scala> cond(foo) { case Foo(1,2, _ @ _*) => true }
res2: Boolean = true

scala> cond(foo) { case Foo(1,2, x) => true }
res3: Boolean = false

scala> cond(goo) { case Foo(1,2, x @ _*) if x exists identity => true }
res4: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I would, except that doesn't allow any of the existing instantiations to work, ie. `Foo(1, 2)` will not compile due to `error: missing arguments for method apply in object Foo`.