# Scala - how to create anonymous class and avoid hiding argument names

Tags: scala

I often encounter the situation where I have a factory method for some trait and the names of the arguments clash with the members of the trait causing them to be hidden:

```
trait MyTrait {
    val a: Int
    val b: String
}

object MyTrait {
    def apply(a: Int, b: String): MyTrait = new MyTrait {
        val a = a // Recursive infinite loop.
        val b = b
    }
}
```

So usually I have to do something ugly like:

```
    def apply(aA: Int, bB: String): MyTrait = new MyTrait {
      val a = aA
      val b = bB
    }
```

or make local copies of the arguments:

```
    def apply(a: Int, b: String): MyTrait = {
      val localA = a
      val localB = b

      new MyTrait {          
          val a = localA
          val b = localB
    }
```

I would like the parameters to the `apply` method to be the same as the members of my trait, so that client code reads nicely when I used named parameters: e.g. `MyTrait(a=3,b="123")`.

Is there a neater mechanism that lets me capture the outer scope where the argument parameters are defined, but the anonymous class isn't yet? For example something like:

```
    def apply(a: Int, b: String): MyTrait = { outer =>
        new MyTrait {
            val a = outer.a
            val b = outer.b
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/12229005/1296806

Answer (score 2):

If we need to create an instance, why not delegate it to the constructor. So I can think of this hack:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def a: Int
  def b: String
}

object MyTrait {
  private class MkMyTrait(val a: Int, val b: String) extends MyTrait
  def apply(a: Int, b: String): MyTrait = new MkMyTrait(a, b)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That only really works for me if my implementation of the trait is a straight pass through of data as in your example. There are often times when I'm creating some specialist  implementation and I need to use the `new` keyword. I was only keeping the example simple to highlight the issue.

Answer (score 2):

My answer to the dupe, which doesn't save much:

```
trait T { val t: Int }
object T {
  def apply(t: Int): T = new {
    private[this] val x = t
  } with T {
    val t = x
  }
}
```

Also, -optimise doesn't get rid of the field.

Here's a different idea: alias the param name.

Soon, we'll be able to filter warnings selectively, so it will be possible to ignore the warning that is generated when deprecation is enabled:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait T { val t: Int }
object T {
  def apply(@deprecatedName('t) t0: Int): T = new T { val t = t0 }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait T
defined object T

scala> T(t = 42)
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res1: T = T$$anon$1@6ea1bcdc
```