# Using an implicit parameter in a recursive function

Tags: scala

Consider the following hypothetical binary tree traversal code:

```
def visitAll(node: Node, visited: Set[Node]): Unit = {
  val newVisited = visited + node
  if (visited contains node) throw new RuntimeException("Cyclic tree definition")
  else if (node.hasLeft) visitAll(node.left, newVisited)
  else if (node.hasRight) visitAll(node.right, newVisited)
  else ()
}
```

I would like to reduce duplication by making the `visited` parameter implicit, like so:

```
def visitAll(node: Node)(implicit visited: Set[Node]): Unit = {
  implicit val newVisited = visited + node
  if (visited contains node) throw new RuntimeException("Cyclic tree definition")
  else if (node.hasLeft) visitAll(node.left) // newVisited passed implicitly
  else if (node.hasRight) visitAll(node.right) // newVisited passed implicitly
  else ()
}
```

however, this gives the following compile error:

> ambiguous implicit values: both value `visited` of type `Set[Node]` and value `newVisited` of type `scala.collection.immutable.Set[Node]` match expected type `Set[Node]`

Is there a way I can tell the compiler to just "expect" an implicit value for the `visited` parameter, but not to use it as the implicit value when recursively invoking the method?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly there is no annotation-based solution, like `(@noPropagate implicit visited: Set[Node])`, so you have to shadow it:

```
scala> def visitAll(node: Node)(implicit visited: Set[Node]): Unit = {
     |     implicit val visited = Set[Node]()
     |     visitAll(node)
     | }
visitAll: (node: Node)(implicit visited: Set[Node])Unit
```

However, it doesn't work if you want to access shadowed value:

```
scala> def visitAll(node: Node)(implicit visited: Set[Node]): Unit = {
     |     val unshadowed: Set[Node] = visited
     |     implicit val visited: Set[Node] = unshadowed
     |     visitAll(node)
     | }
<console>:10: error: forward reference extends over definition of value unshadow
ed
           val unshadowed: Set[Node] = visited
                                       ^
```

So, this may help (checked with REPL) then:

```
def visitAll(node: Node)(implicit visited: Set[Node]): Unit = {     
  val newVisited = visited + node
  ;{
     implicit val visited = newVisited
     if (visited contains node) throw new RuntimeException("Cyclic tree definition")
     else if (node.hasLeft) visitAll(node.left) // newVisited passed implicitly
     else if (node.hasRight) visitAll(node.right) // newVisited passed implicitly
     else ()
  }    
}
```

Or this:

```
def visitAll(node: Node)(implicit visited: Set[Node]): Unit = {     
    ({implicit visited: Set[Node] => 
       if (visited contains node) throw new RuntimeException("Cyclic tree definition")
       else if (node.hasLeft) visitAll(node.left) // newVisited passed implicitly
       else if (node.hasRight) visitAll(node.right) // newVisited passed implicitly
       else ()
    })(visited + node)    
}
```

The idea is to move your shadowed implicit inside some nested block of code

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a syntactic solution to this. Doesn't it feel like a design flaw that declaring that a parameter may be passed to the function implicitly implies that the same parameter is an implicit value in the scope of the function?

Comment: @Zoltán The syntactic solution is shadowing. The rule for implicit is that rules for overloading are used when two candidates are in scope. And a candidate must be accessible by its simple name. In fact, I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: @Zoltan something like `(@noPropagate implicit visited: Set[Node])` would be better, but current scala have nothing like this as far as I know. You may propose it in [scala-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-user) group. Btw, I've added simpler solution to the answer

Answer (score -1):

Shadow the incoming implicit.

The syntactic solution is shadowing. The rule for implicits is that overloading resolution is used when two candidates are in scope. And a candidate must be accessible by its simple name.

```
scala> def f(implicit s: String): String = {
     |   val s0 = s
     |   if (s.length > 10) s else {
     |     implicit val s: String = s0 + "more"
     |     f
     |   }
     | }
f: (implicit s: String)String

scala> f("hi")
res0: String = himoremoremore
```

It's possible to avoid shadowing and renaming if you can leverage overload resolution. Here, the type `P2` means "prepared for recursive call."

```
scala> trait P ; trait P2 extends P
defined trait P
defined trait P2

scala> def f(implicit p: P): String = {
     |   if (p.toString.length > 10) p.toString else {
     |     implicit val p2: P2 = new P2 { override def toString = p.toString + "more" }
     |     f
     |   }}
f: (implicit p: P)String

scala> f(new P2 { override def toString = "hi" })
res1: String = himoremoremore
```

I'm too sick today to do useful work...

Comment: I did try it, but it can't access original `visited` when I do `val visited = visited + node`

Comment: @dk14 I hope my multiline edit makes it more clear. You have to alias the parameter; there are other SO questions about how access a shadowed parameter (because you can't directly).

Comment: actually `s = s0 + more` instead of `s = "hi"`makes it more clear. And it works only if `s` is inside nested block (I also tried to shadow it without, before comment), so our both solutions are pretty ugly, seems like we deserve "-1".

Comment: @dk14 for the record, I didn't downvote either of you :)

Comment: @dk14 see my comment to my answer to the similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12239654/1296806 So answer is as ugly as the question. But Scala caters to the common case, where you pass the same implicit down the stack.

Comment: @dk14 OK, a version without shadowing and with useful types.